Different non-isomorphic versions of natural numbers in different models of ZFC, how could it be possible?
When I search for "first-ordered logic", I came across the following article from Wikipedia in which it is claimed that "No first-order theory, however, has the strength to uniquely describe a structure with an infinite domain, such as the natural numbers or the real line":

First-order logic is the standard for the formalization of mathematics into axioms, and is studied in the foundations of mathematics. Peano arithmetic and Zermelo–Fraenkel set theory are axiomatizations of number theory and set theory, respectively, into first-order logic. No first-order theory, however, has the strength to uniquely describe a structure with an infinite domain, such as the natural numbers or the real line. Axiom systems that do fully describe these two structures, i.e. categorical axiom systems, can be obtained in stronger logics such as second-order logic.

Noah Schweber in the following thread (Why ZFC+FOL cannot uniquely describe/characterize $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{N}$?) stated that:

no set of first-order sentences characterizes $\mathbb{N}$ up to isomorphism. The same is true for any other infinite structure

As I understand, "isomorphism" roughly means "have the same characteristics/ behaviors".
If I concentrate on ZFC, there are many models of ZFC. And from the above statement of Noah Schweber, I understand that for each model $i$ of ZFC, there exists a set $\mathbb{N}_i$ corresponding, and these sets $\mathbb{N}_i$ are not isomorphic.
I'm very confused as it seems to me we are modelling the same thing (i.e. create "something" that looks like "natural numbers" in our mind, with the behaviors that we are expecting), but in fact they don't have the same behaviors, etc. It is like the natural number 3 in the universe of ZFC is different from the number 3 in the universe of $ZFC^{'}$ whereas ZFC and $ZFC^{'}$ are modelling basically the same things which are "the sentences of set theory" (even if the starting axioms may be different, and the logical rules may also be different).
I think there is a flaw in my understanding of different models of ZFC but I can't figure out where. Could you please enlighten me about this subject ? Many thanks!

Edit: In my understanding, a model of a theory can be expressed by the following schema

If I am not mistaken, when we speak about different models of ZFC, we are talking about the green part of the schema, while keeping unchanged the set of sentences (the purple part). I think that no matter how we choose the starting point (the axioms) and no matter how we reason, what we are trying to model stay the same, therefore the modelled object should be the same (or at least have the same behavior).

Edit 2: With the comment of David Gao, I edit the picture to show my understanding of the model as a "framework" in which we define a structure (along with some objects in it). Then a theory will function within this framework by stating some sentences about the "objects" predefined in the structure.


Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
